# Get data and after that routing

Tags: angularjs

I want to make $http request, get results and according to data i get to route to view1 or view2. How can i do it in angular? Does somebody have example?

It should be some

```
$http({
            url: 'API/v1/User/GetUserInfo',
            method: "GET",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            //Something like this
                var myVar=data.myVariable;
                if(myVar==1){
                     $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/view1' });
                }else{
                     $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/view2' });
                 }

        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.error = "There are problems with connection to server. Status:" + status + " Please, try to connect later.";
            $scope.validationClass = "invalid";
        });
```

and after that

Answer (score 0):

Use to `$location` service to go to a specific path/route. Angular routing listens to changes on the location and will trigger all necessary actions.

```
if (myVar == 1) {
    $location.url('/view1');
} else {
    $location.url('/view2');
}
```